# How to Render Navisworks(*.nwd) file to IOS

Tags: ios, 3d, revit, autodesk-navisworks

I want to export Navisworks 3D navigation models to my IPhone device , Is there any API available to achieve this. I want to create my Own App to read models into IOS - similar to Navisworks Freedom viewer for IOS.

I have lots searched on internet but couldn't find any useful.

Comment: Sorry, this site is not for library recommendations.

Comment: I am not asking for any kind of library, just simple How can I achieve 3D navigation model into IOS ???

Comment: Well, then you are assuming that there is a built in way to do this.  There is not.  It is a very complicated process that would add tons of unneeded bloat to iOS.  Most likely you will have to convert it to another file format, or figure out the structure of the file format and parse it into OpenGL ES yourself.

Comment: Ok. I understand so there's no other easy way to do this ??

Comment: is it possible using UNITY 3D Frameworks as revitzo has been ??

Answer (score 2):

There is no Navisworks viewer for iOS, but there is a WebGL viewer that can be embedded on mobile apps (or web or desktop too).

- There is a live sample at https://360.autodesk.com/viewer
- See the API at http://developer.autodesk.com
- iOS sample at https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/workflow-ios-view.and.data.api

Answer (score 1):

I recommend developing your own native or web app to build a mobile 3d model viewer.

Web App - you could use Unity3d or Three.js. These communities are strong and there are plenty of resources available. The benefit here is that it would work on desktop too.

Native app - You could make a model viewer in Swift using Apple's Metal library. I am not familiar with Android 3d shader libraries.

Both of these endeavours are huge amounts of works. I hope you would keep any eye out for code you can copyright (or open source), perhaps even patent if you develop a new, complex algorithm for converting/displaying 3d data.